# Visualising frequency response from sensor and raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, i2c, hardware-acceleration, frequency-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRLfS.png)import time

```
import board
import busio
from adafruit_lsm6ds.lsm6ds33 import LSM6DS33

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
sensor = LSM6DS33(i2c)

while True:
     print(sensor.acceleration)
     time.sleep(0.25)
```

Hello everyone I am using `lsm6ds33` 3D accelerations sensors and raspberry pi for my project.
Currently i am able to acquire 3D raw data of acceleration using I2C interface and visualise it using Mu plotter. I want to visualise the frequency response of the sensors using python. Since i am new to python, anyone can help me please. I have attached screenshot please have a look.

Sincerely

[LSM6DS33_I2C_INTERFACE_FREQUENCY_RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDwJB.png)

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: Use in-kernel driver _drivers/iio/imu/st_lsm6dsx/_. Why do you not use it?

Comment: Hi 0andriy i am beginner in python and linux kernal. Can you please explain how i can do this

Comment: Hello everyone can you please tell me how i can imlpement this